# Flamingo (Anthurium) leaves turning yellowish

Tags: diagnosis, flowers, indoors, watering, leaves

I have this Flamingo plant (Anthrium) for the last month.
I use P rich fertilizer on it. Sometimes it gets occasional sunlight (Might be 2 days a week). It is kept in a room where it gets diffuse light most of the day.

Yesterday I noticed that one of my leaves is turning yellow and it has some holes in it too.
I could not find any pest under the leaves though.

Please find the attached pictures of the leaf.

[image]

[image]

Could anyone guess what is happening to this plant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be absolutely certain that your plant is pest-free. Those pesky little buggers can be very difficult to spot. Best to search for them at night when they usually do most of their feeding. Other then that, those holes might be an indication of environmental stress caused by lack of adequate humidity of too much heat. Where is the plant located? Is it anywhere near heat ducts, ventilator grills or drafts? What's the air around like? And what exactly do you mean by occasional sunlight? Do you place it in direct light 2 days a week? You do know that this is a shade plant right? Changing the light conditions suddenly and so frequently would cause harm to any plant let alone a flamingo.

Comment: probably this was the problem: I kept it at the sunny window 2 days a week for last few weeks. May be I need to remove them from there. The air is also dry now.